# Parse Querying error

Tags: javascript, html, parse-platform

I'm trying to query for users i follow who using Parse.com javascript API.

The code gives error `400 bad request`. My code is:

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.containedIn(Parse.User.current().get("peopleIFollow"));
query.find( {
```

and that throws error 400 bad request from parse's servers

Comment: You should post more code becase that what you posted isnt completed. There is a open `{`

Comment: It should be `query.containedIn("field name", [...])`